# Accessing session from a helper spec in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I have a method in my ApplicationHelper that checks to see if there are any items in my basket

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def has_basket_items?
    basket = Basket.find(session[:basket_id])
    basket ? !basket.basket_items.empty? : false
  end
end
```

Here is my helper spec that I have to test this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe 'has_basket_items?' do
    describe 'with no basket' do

      it "should return false" do
        helper.has_basket_items?.should be_false
      end

    end
  end
end
```

however when I run the test i get

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/testing/test_process.rb:13:
```

From debugging this i see that *session* is being accessed in ActionDispatch::TestProcess from @request.session, and @request is nil. When i access the session from my request specs @request is an instance of ActionController::TestRequest.

My question is can I access the session object from a helper spec? If I can, how? And if I cant what is the best practice to test this method?

*****UPDATE***********

This was down to having `include ActionDispatch::TestProcess` in my factories. Removing this include sorts the problem.

Comment: To attach files using FactoryGirl and without "ActionDispatch::TestProcess", use: `image {  Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new('spec/factories/test.png', 'image/png') }`, see: https://gist.github.com/rugginoso/4079399 and https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/512

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*can I access the session object from a helper spec?*

Yes.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def has_basket_items?
    raise session.inspect
    basket = Basket.find(session[:basket_id])
    basket ? !basket.basket_items.empty? : false
  end
end

$ rspec spec/helpers/application_helper.rb

Failure/Error: helper.has_basket_items?.should be_false
  RuntimeError:
    {}
```

The session object is there and returns an empty hash.

Try reviewing the backtrace in more detail to find the error.  `stack level too deep` usually indicates recursion gone awry.

Comment: Unfortunately that gives the same stack too deep error too. Debugging the recursion goes to the session method in  ActionDispatch::TestProcess which calls `@request.session` and @request is nil.  `@request.session` seems to call session on ActionDispatch::TestProcess and so this loops until the stack is too deep. From this I think that i need to somehow inject a session into the helper, but I cant seem to work out how.

Comment: I ran the code in my answer and got the empty hash as output. That suggests something might be wrong with your environment. I'd try a clean Rails install into a new project, see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Ok, so after a bit of experimentation i found that it is the `factory_girl_rails` gem that is causing my headaches, which is pretty annoying as i have hundreds of tests that uses it. Am going to see if there is any fixes for it, otherwise it looks like I'm going to have to find a replacement for factory girl. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Further inspection has shown that is was down to having `include ActionDispatch::TestProcess` in my factories as i was using `fixture_file_upload` to include test images in my models. As I don't actually use these i have removed them. Phew!

Answer (score 2):

You are testing has_basket_items? action in ApplicationHelper, which check a specfic basket with a basket_id in the baskets table, so you should have some basket objects in your test which you can create using [Factory_Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) gem.

Hers's an example :-

```
basket1 = Factory(:basket, :name => 'basket_1')
basket2 = Factory(:basket, :name => 'basket_2')
```

You can get more details on How to use factory_girl from this screen cast http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures

It will create a Factory object in your test database. So, basically you can create some factory objects and then set a basket_id in session to check for its existence like this :

```
session[:basket_id] = basket1.id
```

So, your test should be like this :-

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe 'has_basket_items?' do
    describe 'with no basket' do

      it "should return false" do
        basket1 = Factory(:basket, :name => 'basket_1')
        basket2 = Factory(:basket, :name => 'basket_2')
        session[:basket_id] = 1234 # a random basket_id 
        helper.has_basket_items?.should be_false
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can check for a basket_id which is being created by factory_girl to be_true by using :

```
session[:basket_id] = basket1.id
helper.has_basket_items?.should be_true
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but unfortunately i get the same result. From what I can tell this seems to be more to the fact that a request object has not been injected into my helper rather than the objects don't exist in the database. In fact, no basket entities should have to exist for my method to work.