# include ActionDispatch::TestProcess prevents guard from reloading properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rspec, guard

I'm using fixture_file_upload to test some file uploads in my rspecs

If I just put it in the spec I get an error for method not found.

To get it working I put include ActionDispatch::TestProcess in my spec but I have found since I did that, that guard is not correctly reloading spec files when I make changes, it keeps running the tests against the old version of the files.

I can work around this by stopping and restarting guard, but it kind of defeats the purpose.

How do I prevent this from happening? How should I reference fixture_file_upload or where should I put the include?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know the exact source of the problem, but I have had some strange issues caused by `ActionDispatch::TestProcess` myself. You can, however, use [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13673639/454094#comment35259918_13673639) instead of `fixture_file_upload`, meaning you can remove the problematic `include`.

If you have something like this (e.g. in a factory):

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

fixture_file_upload('spec/factories/test.png', 'image/png')
```

you can replace it with:

```
Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new('spec/factories/test.png', 'image/png')
```

If you look at the source of [`fixture_file_upload`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/fixture_file_upload) you'll see it essentially just calls the above code.

Comment: Fwiw: including `ActionDispatch::TestProcess` globally (which is what happens in a factory file afaik) adds more than just the `fixture_file_upload` method, and what's worse, it adds it to `Object`. Some of the other methods it adds are `#session` and `#cookies`. Those methods will be overloaded with the `ActionDispatch::TestProcess` versions inside *any classes* which were previously defined at the time of include. This is bad news for a lot of reasons, and I suspect it causes a lot of hard-to-debug problems.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, that sure shines some light on what might be causing the problem.