# Attaching ActiveStorage files in factorybot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rails-activestorage

I'm looking for a way to create factories for models which have active storage attachments

I attempted the method in [this post](https://blog.eq8.eu/til/factory-bot-trait-for-active-storange-has_attached.html)

with my factory

```
factory :activity_fit_file, class: 'Activity' do
    association :user, factory: :user
    activity_type {:cycling}
    original_activity_log_file { fixture_file_upload("#{Rails.root}/spec/files/example_fit_file.fit") }
end
```

but I got this error

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `fixture_file_upload' for #<FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner:0x000000000208c5f8>
```

What is the correct way to attach files in ActiveStorage?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try with `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` directly:

```
file { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new('path', 'image/png') }
```

Comment: `undefined method upload' for nil:NilClass`

`# /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:155:in upload'`

Comment: Could be the file path, try with `spec/files/example_fit_file.fit`

Comment: Ok this was the solution but I forgot to set config.active_storage.service in my test env

Comment: This was working for me for years but after updating to Rails 6.1.3, it's getting an `ActiveStorage::IntegrityError` error. There isn't much information about that error either.

Comment: @Archonic I know it has been a while, but did you figure out what was causing the `ActiveStorage::IntegrityError` in this situation?  I suddenly started seeing it on a project using Rails 5.2.0. The gems and configuration were not changed recently either.

Comment: @joe It actually wasn't the Rails upgrade but a Docker for Mac bug. I wrote about it here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41991

Comment: @Archonic Thank you, I was using Docker as well, so it looks like the same bug is present on Docker for Linux too.

Answer (score 36):

This solution works with rails 6:

```
factory :post do
  # ...
  after(:build) do |post|
    post.image.attach(
      io: File.open(Rails.root.join('test', 'fixture_files', 'test.jpg')),
      filename: 'test.jpg',
      content_type: 'image/jpeg'
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution for Rails 6+. Note that you can also use FactoryBot [transient attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#with-callbacks) to pass attachment-related information in with your model, e.g. `after(:build) { |item, ev| item.image.attach(io: File.open(ev.image_path, 'rb'), filename: File.basename(ev.image_path), content_type: MiniMime.lookup_by_filename(ev.image_path)) if ev.image_path }`

Comment: I can confirm that this works.  I switched to this after suddenly getting `ActiveStorage::IntegrityError` with the `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` approach after months without errors :shrugs:

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the following it will work.

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
factory :activity_fit_file, class: 'Activity' do
    association :user, factory: :user
    activity_type {:cycling}
    original_activity_log_file { fixture_file_upload("#{Rails.root}/spec/files/example_fit_file.fit") }
end
```

Comment: It is not recommended to include `ActionDispatch::TestProcess` because it
includes other methods such as `#session` which override existing methods on *all objects*.  See: https://github.com/honeybadger-io/honeybadger-ruby/blob/a18b1c3c4d912f96f1a3cb1435cc8a50e436f7f5/lib/honeybadger/notice.rb#L487 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23220853/1296731