# How to define attached file in a factory without using file fixtures

Tags: factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a model that

```rb
has_one_attached :csv
```

And I want to define that field in a factory, like this:

```rb
csv do
      Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(StringIO.new(<<~CSV), 'text/csv', original_filename: "file.csv")
        Some, Columns, Here
      CSV
end
```

Because it looks like the devs of `Rack::Test` actually [expected that use case](https://github.com/rack/rack-test/blob/ab9ba9c2d272b3852f0f46849f88b4522851878f/lib/rack/test/uploaded_file.rb#L34).

But when I try to create an object using this factory, I get

```
     NoMethodError:
       private method `open' called for #<StringIO:0x00007f206ff88d38>
     
               tempfile.public_send(method_name, *args, &block)
```

Which seems to be coming from here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/changes/create_one.rb#L58

and deeper in the stack trace from here:
https://github.com/rack/rack-test/blob/ab9ba9c2d272b3852f0f46849f88b4522851878f/lib/rack/test/uploaded_file.rb#L51

```rb
      # Delegate all methods not handled to the tempfile.
      def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
        tempfile.public_send(method_name, *args, &block)
      end
```

where tempfile is set to my StringIO instance, like this:

```rb
      def initialize_from_stringio(stringio, original_filename)
        @tempfile = stringio
        @original_filename = original_filename || raise(ArgumentError, 'Missing `original_filename` for StringIO object')
      end
```

So it looks like StringIO should not be used like that because my instance does not have the `.open` method (StringIO class does).

But to recap:

- Rack::Test seems to allow using StringIO
- ActiveStorage [seems to know about Rack::Test::UploadedFile](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/changes/create_one.rb#L56)

Is this a bug in either of those gems, or am I using this feature wrong?

#### Edit:

This "hack" seems to be fixing it:

```rb
    csv do
      file = StringIO.new(<<~CSV)
        Some, Columns, Here
      CSV

      # There seems to be a bug, when using StringIO with Rack::Test::UploadedFile
      # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141549/attaching-activestorage-files-in-factorybot
      file.class_eval do
        def open = reopen
      end

      Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(file, "text/csv", original_filename: "enrollments_changes_report.csv")
    end
```

Basically one can use StringIO or Tempfile with the `Rack::Test::UploadedFile`. Tempfile's instance has `#open` method (for which the docs state it opens or reopens the file), but `StringIO` does not have `#open` (it does have `#reopen`, though). Which makes me lean towards thinking it is an actual bug.

Comment: After some extensive investigation I concluded it must be a bug in the way ActiveStorage is using rack-test. And opened a PR to Rails https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/47725, I'll update the question/provide an answer when it's concluded.